# Hash value null error in react-native hooks useEffect

Tags: react-native, hook

the hash data I received using asyncStorage in my react native project is wrong. It actually works when I refresh the page. My request is probably running earlier than hash. However, I could not find a solution to this.

```
 const [info, setInfo] = useState('');
 const [hash, setHash] = useState(null);

  const _retrieveData = async () => {
        try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('hash');
           setHash(value)
        } catch (error) {
            // Error retrieving data
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        _retrieveData()
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(hash) //
            axios.get(apiUrl + 'loginInfo?hash=' + hash)
                .then(response => {
                    setInfo(response.data.message);
                    console.log('res', response);
                });
        }, 1000);

    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by getting help from a friend.

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState({});
const [hash, setHash] = useState(null);

const _retrieveData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('hash');
        setHash(value);
    } catch (error) {
        // Error retrieving data
    }
}, []);

const getInfo = useCallback(async () => {

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(apiUrl + 'loginInfo?hash=' + hash);
        setInfo(response.data.message)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}, [hash]); 

useEffect(() => {
    if (!hash) {
        _retrieveData();
    }
}, [hash]) 


useEffect(() => {
    if (hash) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            getInfo();
        },500)
    }
}, [hash, getInfo]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The _retriveData method should be inside of the useEffect.

```js
const [info, setInfo] = useState('');
const [hash, setHash] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {

    const _retrieveData = async () => {
        try {
            const hash = await AsyncStorage.getItem('hash');
            return hash
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error',error);
        // Error retrieving data
        }
    };

    const hash = _retrieveData()

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(hash) //
        axios.get(apiUrl + 'loginInfo?hash=' + hash)
            .then(response => {
                setInfo(response.data.message);
                console.log('res', response);
            });
    }, 1000);

}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but the problem is not solved.